# How to get FigureCanvasTkAgg to work with Scrollbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to plot inside a tkinter application. In the final program there will be many subplots arranged vertically, more than fit on the screen. So I want to have a reasonably sized window with a scrollbar to scroll down.

Starting from an example with Canvas found here [Tkinter Scrollbar Patterns](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm) I created this minimal example of my struggling:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas, Scrollbar, HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL, BOTH, X, Y, BOTTOM, RIGHT, LEFT, S, N, W, E
from numpy import arange, sin
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class Test(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self, None)
        self.frame=Frame(None)
        self.frame.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.frame.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)

        fig = Figure()

        xval = arange(200)/10.
        yval = sin(xval)

        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax1.plot(xval, yval)

        self.hbar=Scrollbar(self.frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.vbar=Scrollbar(self.frame,orient=VERTICAL)

        self.canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.frame)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().config(bg='#FFFFFF',scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().config(width=300,height=300)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().config(xscrollcommand=self.hbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.vbar.set)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.hbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W+E)
        self.hbar.config(command=self.canvas.get_tk_widget().xview)
        self.vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
        self.vbar.config(command=self.canvas.get_tk_widget().yview)

        self.frame.config(width=100, height=100) # this has no effect

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = Test()
    app.mainloop()
```

Here are my main 2 problems:

1. When I resize the window, the scrollbar is static, i.e. if I decrease the window size with the mouse drag, it dissappears with the rest of the plot
2. More importantly: if I increase the canvas size in the code, the window size is also increased. I tried adding a `self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid_propagate(0)` without success...

I need the window size to be smaller than the plot size at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = Test()
    app.rowconfigure( 0, weight=1 )     # You need to add this. 
    app.columnconfigure( 0, weight=1 )  # You need to add this.

    app.mainloop()
```

Your `Tk` window has a child `tk.Frame` widget, i.e. `Tk.frame`, located at the `Tk` window's (0,0) grid position. The size of `Tk.frame` by default will be the size of it's child widget(s), which presently is a matplotlib backend `FigureCanvasTkAgg` object that has a `tk.Canvas` widget, i.e. `Tk.frame.canvas.get_tk_widget()`, which you have set to be 300x300 pixels wide and high.

You need these additional two lines to instruct the `Tk` window's grid cell (0,0) to be stretchable. That is, cell (0,0) border should stretch to "touch the `Tk` window's border at all times". This action ensures the size of `Tk.frame` is always the size of the `Tk` window.

Presently, when you resize the `Tk` window without the added lines, you are seeing the `Tk` window resizing with the size of `Tk.frame` remaining constant at 300x300 pixels wide and high.